# how to clear `double` in generic c++ code?

Tags: c++, generics, smart-pointers, generic-programming

I'm writing a function that averages every 10 units of a 100 unit vector. I have to clear a temporary sum after every 10 iterations. 
Normally, I would write `ave=0.0` but if the `ave` is not a double but some type `T`, I run into problems. For example if I average over points with xyz coordinate,s I can't do `{x,y,z} = 0.0`

to work around, I tried to create a smart pointer and then reset it. that gave me seg fault.
what is the best way to clear an object that doesn't have a specified type?

```
template <class T>
vector<T> average(const vector<T> &v, const int n) {
  vector<T> ave_vec;
  int iave = 0;
  shared_ptr<T> ave(new T);
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    *ave += v[i];
    iave++;
    if (iave == n) {
      ave_vec.push_back(*ave/n);
      ave.reset(); ///> gives seg fault
      iave=0;
    }
  }
  return ave_vec;
}
```

if I replace `ave.reset()` with `ave = 0.0`, the code works.

Comment: What is the intent of your `average` function? It does not calculate the average, but does something different.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas it takes a vector of size `v.size()`, averages every `n` elements, and outputs a vector of size `v.size()/n`. I do this to reduce load time for gnuplot. when i have to plot a vector of size 10_000_000, i run this function and get a vector of size 1000. 1000 have almost the same value but i need them because I wanted a high precision from my symplectic ode integrator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To initialize it:

```
T ave = T();
```

and to reset it:

```
ave = T();
```

Comment: what's wrong with using a smart pointer? if `T` is a big object, using smart pointer will be better on memory, right?

Comment: @kirill_igum: I didn't say there was anything wrong with using a smart pointer.  You said you made it a smart pointer as a workaround for the problem of trying to reset the value.  That workaround was unnecessary, so I didn't include it in my solution.

Comment: @kirill_igum: In response to your second question, what do you mean by "better on memory"?  Take up less space?  No.  Take up less space on the stack? Maybe, but if you're using objects that are so large that creating one on the stack is a problem, then you're using a faulty class, and you should stop using it.  If you really wanted to make it a smart pointer though, there is no reason for it to be shared_ptr, since there's no sharing going on.

Answer (score 2):

If `ave` is a `shared_ptr<T>`, try this to reset `ave` to a default-initialized `T`:

```
*ave = T();
```